# Increment date based on condition Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Is there a way to increment a datetime column using a case-switch or if-elif chain in Pandas?

```
def due_date(row):

    if 5 <= row['num_1'] <= 10:
        result = pd.to_datetime(row['date']) + pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(pd.DateOffset(1))

    elif 10 <= row['num_1'] <= 15:
        result = pd.to_datetime(row['date']) + pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(pd.DateOffset(5))

    elif 15 <= row['num_1'] <= 20:
        result = pd.to_datetime(row['date']) + pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(pd.DateOffset(10))

    elif 20 <= row['num_1'] <= 25:
        result = pd.to_datetime(row['date']) + pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(pd.DateOffset(15))

    return result
```

This doesn't seem to work. :(
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you don't try to use `np.where`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
deltas = pd.to_timedeltas(
    pd.cut(
        df[‘num_1’],
        [5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
        labels=[1, 5, 10, 15]
    ),
    unit=‘D’
)

pd.to_datetime(df[‘date’]) + deltas
```